# Getting a better understanding of callbacks with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Can anyone explain to me what is going here?

I have been learning node and callbacks and I am kind of getting the concept but can use some more details.

So in function "myCallback" there is a log to console but in "usingItNow" there is no log to console and the result are "from myCallback From Using it" in the console.

How is it I do not need something like return in usingItNow?

Is this a proper representation for usingItNow if it were not a callback?
var usingItNow = 'From Using it'

Can someone post some links to some good tuts?

Is usingItNow proper camelcase or should it be usingItnow?

```
var myCallback = function(data) {
    console.log('from myCallback ' + data);
};

var usingItNow = function(callback) {
    callback('From Using it');
};

usingItNow(myCallback);
```

Comment: Standard good tutorials (first 2 on google) 1) http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/ 2) http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/ ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code: `usingItNow(myCallback);`

You are invoking the function `usingItNow` and passing it function `myCallback`.

Inside `usingItNow` you are executing your parameter `callback` by doing this `callback('From Using it')` you are essentially doing `myCallback('From Using it')` because `callback` is equal to `myCallback`.

You don't need to return anything because `myCallback` is doing the logging.

Your camel case is fine.

Comment: Thanks I actually ran out and picked up Sams Teach yourself node. The 4th chapter does a good job explaining as well.